# The definition of prime numbers.

Tags: predicate-logic, proof-explanation

My textbook gives the definition of prime numbers as such:

> To say that *x is a prime number* means that $x \in N$ and $x \neq 1$ and $\forall a \in N$, $\forall b \in N$, if $x=ab$, then $a=1$ or $b=1$.

I don't understand this definition of prime numbers.

Let's say I choose $x=10$, which I know not to be a prime number. Then $x=10=10 \times 1$ where I have chosen $a=10$ and $b=1$. Doesn't this fulfill the previous definition but also show that it doesn't hold?

Thank you in advance for helping up to clear any confusion.

Comment: For all $a$ and $b$, not just some.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are misunderstanding how quantifiers ($\forall$ "for all" and $\exists$ "there exists") work.

A number $p$ is prime if **for any** $a, b$ with $ab=p$, we have $a=1$ or $b=1$.

$10$ is not prime because we can take $a=5, b=2$ - that is, there exists **some** pair $a, b$ with $ab=p$ but $a\not=1\not=b$.

In order for a statement of the form "$\forall a . . .$" to hold, the inner statement has to hold *no matter what* $a$ you pick: so finding some $a$ for which it works, tells you nothing. Basically, you need to show that *no counterexample exists*.